# Separating email server and application server

Tags: php, email, pear, mail-server

I have been assigned a task to separate email server and application server. I have little knowledge of server. I am using PHP. Earlier I use to send using phpmailer class. Now I have been asked to implement using PEAR and separating email server and application server. I have been told that we need to provide only the IP of the email server from the application server while sending email from the application server.
Please suggest me I don't know how to proceed with it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello Liri. In order for anyone to be able to answer this question, you're going to need to be more specific. For example, what server software are you currently using? How is you application currently setup? Can I suggest you read the StackOverflow FAQs - http://stackoverflow.com/faq/. Also, if you're not sure about the scope of the project it's probably best to discuss it with your supervisor.

Comment: thanks Aaron I consult with my supervisor and will try to get more specific